# c# Fill datagridviewcell from another datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two datagridviews in my code.

- One of them is the maingrid, which is connected to a database.
- The second one is only a list with one column.

I wrote an event for doubleclicking a cell in the second grid

```
    private void xmlGrid_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string cellContent = xmlGrid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(cellContent);

    }
```

The first grid has 4 columns "id|ChannelNumber|ChannelName|XMLChannelName"

The first 3 Columns are filled from the database. The 4. column should be filled by the value of the doubleclick event with the text.

This Event should fill the XMLChannelname Cell of the selected row in the first grid with the value text from the event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over rows in first grid (say Grid1) and figure out which row will get the value from second grid (say Grid2). Lets assume that `ChannelName` column is used to decide which row will get value. Then following will work:

```
private void xmlGrid_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string cellContent = xmlGrid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

    if(Grid1.SelectedRows.Count==0) return;

    var row = Grid1.SelectedRows[0];
    row.Cells[3].Value=cellContent;
}
```

Comment: No that is not what I mean. I want to set row.Cells[3].Value=cellContent; at the row which is currently selected in grid1

Comment: sorry didn't got `SelectedRow` requirement. It was really late here down under :)